# How to successfully use the callback on an javascript function with an http request

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, callback

Note: I have limited exp with js so correct me if my I'm completely wrong in how I'm describing this scenario.

I have two javascript files. I am calling a function on the first file (client side) which calls a function on the second file and uses the callback from the second file's function for the purposes of `response.success/.error` on the first file.

If that doesn't make sense here is some code:

Note: this is being done temporarily using Parse's cloud functions. Let me know if more information is needed regarding those but not sure if it's important.

## First file:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("methodName", function(request, response) {
    ...
    secondFile.myFunction(param1, {
        stuff: request.params.stuff,
    }, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            response.error(err);
        } else {
            response.success(res);// I'm assuming this is going to the hardcoded "yes." from httpRequest on second file's function
        }
    });
});
```

## Second File:

```
myFunction: function(param1, properties, callback) {
        if (!param1) return callback(new Error("Helpful error message"));

        var headersForReq = {
            ...
        };

        var bodyForReq = ...; // the properties properly parsed


        Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: ...,
            headers: headersForReq,
            body: bodyForReq,
            success: function (httpResponse) {
                callback(null, 'yes'); // the hardcoded "yes" i referred to
            },
            error: function (httpResponse) {
                callback(httpResponse.status + httpResponse.error);
            }
        });
    }
```

On my the client, the code is treated as a success (errors aren't thrown or returned back) but when I print out the value it comes across as (null) not "yes".

What's going on here? (Side note, httpRequest is currently not doing anything, its hard to verify if the request is properly being sent because it's being sent to a third party API).

I do know the second file's method is properly being called though. So it's not a silly issue with the `module.exports` or `var secondFile = require('\path\secondFile')`

Comment: Where/how exactly do you "print out" the value?

Comment: on the client I am calling this Parse "PFCloud" function. It returns an object (whatever you put in the response.success of the first function) or an error if there's an error. for example in the first method if i hardcode `response.success('yes')` instead of `response.success(res)` the console on the client will print out 'yes' as the returned object

Comment: In your client, neither response value shows nor get exception?

Comment: No. The only time a response value shows is when I hardcode something in, as opposed using the `err` or `res` values from the callback

Comment: @ChunTingLin I'm assuming that I'm using the callback correctly though? I copied syntax but wasn't sure if I should pass it null and only pass a res value on the success call, and whether I could get away with only passing the first value (which is supposed to be error) on the error call in the second file

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just mis-use the api

Rewrite it with the example style.
https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Cloud.html#methods_httpRequest

```
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: ...,
        headers: headersForReq,
        body: bodyForReq
    }).then(function (httpResponse) {
            callback(null, 'yes'); // the hardcoded "yes" i referred to
        },
        function (httpResponse) {
            callback(httpResponse.status + httpResponse.error);
        }
    });
```

I think below will work, too.

```
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: ...,
        headers: headersForReq,
        body: bodyForReq
    }, {
        success: function (httpResponse) {
            callback(null, 'yes'); // the hardcoded "yes" i referred to
        },
        error: function (httpResponse) {
            callback(httpResponse.status + httpResponse.error);
        }
    });
```

BTW, if you are using open source parse-server, you can use request or request-promise. These 2 npm package is used by many people. (Parse.Promise is not es6-like promise)